# Installing Cython-0.29.7

Tags: python

I need to install Cython but do not know to execute the .py files. Do please help guide me. Have the folder extracted but am at a loss from there on.

Cython-0.29.7 folder contents:

[image: Cython-0.29.7 folder]

Tried following this link but am unable to execute from the start pip install cython
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXuEoqK4bEc

Comment: See the README.And why link to an image? How am I suppose to look at the contents of the readme from that image of yours?

Answer (score 1):

Install cython using pip.

```
$ pip3 install cython
```

Then run cython

```
$ cython

Cython (http://cython.org) is a compiler for code written in the
Cython language.  Cython is based on Pyrex by Greg Ewing.

Usage: cython [options] sourcefile.{pyx,py}

Options:
  -V, --version                  Display version number of cython compiler
  -l, --create-listing           Write error messages to a listing file
  -I, --include-dir <directory>  Search for include files in named directory
                                 (multiple include directories are allowed).
  -o, --output-file <filename>   Specify name of generated C file
  -t, --timestamps               Only compile newer source files
```

Comment: for install pip:  https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: If you want to install pip, there's no need to follow those commands. Just run `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: this is for hard case :)